# Call a function when a criteria is met - Code.gs

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been struggling with a code for a while now, and I can't seem to find the solution. I hope you can help me. I have a code to add products to a database; I'm basically creating an inventory. The problem I'm facing is that I would like my function to activate when I select an option from a dropdown list. In other words, when that cell contains the specified text, I want the save button (which contains the function) to save the data to a specific sheet. Here's my code:

```
function GuardarRegistro(){
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Registro"); 
  var datos = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Ingresos"); 

  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("F3").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C3").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F8").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F10").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F12").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("F13").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C10").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C12").getValue()]];

  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9).setValues(valores); 

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Datos guardados con éxito');
}
```

At the moment, the function works perfectly fine, but I want the same data to be saved to a different sheet when I choose an option from my dropdown list.

I've tried using the IF function, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it to an already established function.

Comment: First, I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the details of `my dropdown list` and the relationship between `I want the same data to be saved to a different sheet when I choose an option from my dropdown list` and your script? And, can I ask you about the relationship between `I would like my function to activate when I select an option from a dropdown list` and `In other words, when that cell contains the specified text, I want the save button (which contains the function) to save the data to a specific sheet.`? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand it from your question.

Comment: You can use an installable onEdit trigger.  But you haven't provided enough information to write one.